# Difference between 気軽 and 気楽

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I would like to say

> Please feel free to contact me.

I know it is probably

> **気軽に**連絡してください。

But will it be wrong to use 気楽に in this case?

> **気楽に**連絡してください。

What is the difference in nuance between 気軽 and 気楽?

Comment: Just a thought. Would it be wrong to use `何かあったら連絡してください。` instead?

Comment: @john I feel they have a bit different nuance. 何かあったら means " if anything happens", so you need to have a business but I feel 気軽に means "even without business" like "how are you?".

Comment: I agree. Maybe I am misinterpreting it, but I also want to translate it into: "If anything, please contact me", even though "If anything happens" is more correct word for word. Thanks for the opinion though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「気軽{きがる}に連絡{れんらく}してください。」

is just a natural, everyday phrase that "everyone" uses very often.  I do not think anyone would argue about that.

Today, when I saw the following sentence in your question,

> 「気楽{きらく}に連絡してください。」

I had to stop and think about it, which is more often than not a bad sign.  Would I ever say it?  No, I would not;That I know for sure.  Would anyone I personally know say it?  No, I do not think so and that is why I had to stop and really think.  So, would ***anyone*** ever say it?  I suppose, yes, (even though I know I will not follow suit.)

While I might not call the second sentence using 「気楽」 "incorrect", I will at least call it "pretty strange".

> 「**気軽**に + Verb describing a **specific action**」

is a common and valid usage expressing the idea of ***performing a specific action without hesitation, formality, pressure, etc***.  「連絡する (to contact a person)」 is a specific action requiring making a phone call, writing an e-mail or letter, etc.

**Many of us would, however, not often express these ideas using 「気楽に」.  When we use 「気楽に」, we usually refer to "spending time or living with a relaxed state of mind, easy manners", etc.  These are not specific actions.**

"Make yourself at home.", "Take it easy.", "Sit back and relax.", etc. are the ideas behind the expressions such as 「気楽にする」、「気楽に過{す}ごす」、「気楽に生{い}きる」, etc.  Again, these are different from performing specific actions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really appropriate to use 気楽 here. It implies one is unguarded and sounds not necessarily constructive or positive unless it refers to kinds of leisure.

Answer (score 0):

気軽's translations: freely, readily, cheerfully.

気楽's translation: comfortably.

---

> 「気軽」は、ある行動をするときに、負担や障害が少ないということです。常に行動を伴います。

気軽 is when doing something, the burden is low. Always involving acts.

> 「気楽」は気分が楽な状態です。つまり、心配や心の負担がない状態です。行動を伴う必要はありません。

気楽 is when feeling good. Anyway, thn mental burden is low. It does not need involving acts.

Related: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/593447